# First thumbnail Image inCustomized ListView is not Visible

Tags: android-layout, xml-parsing, android-listview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am working on Android GingerBread. I'm using the following tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

for the following XML:

http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml

The problem is, everything is good except that I'm not getting the image of the first node in my Customized ListView thumbnail.

If someone knows the solution, it would be highly appreciated. I've tried several times cleaning and refreshing the project but no use.

Comment: I downloaded the code and I run it on my Emulator and it works just fine. Are you sure you only have problem with `Adele`'s image?

Comment: Yes. But I've solved this problem by replacing another Adele's image into it and it works fine :)